# Does this sound like a bad bearing on the blower fan? (burner of oil-powered boiler)

Tags: boiler, pump, noise, blower

There are a number posts about whining sounds, but it's hard to know if the posters are talking about the same kind of sound I'm hearing. It's coming from the burner of our oil-powered boiler but I can't quite locate the source of the noise by listening. Does it sound like a bad bearing on the blower motor or a pump issue? It just started happening on the burner, which is about 10 years old. It is when the boiler is first beginning to respond for a call for heat and has ignited, and then the noise fades away after a minute or so.

[noise from burner of oil-powered boiler](https://vimeo.com/673706064)

Comment: I will take a SWAG and say it is the oil pump. I hear metal against metal at a relative high speed. Keep an eye on it , if it does not get worse get it repaired in the spring.

Comment: @Gil. Thanks for the SWAG :-)  Here the DIY aspect is me asking the service tech to bring a spare pump with him on the upcoming annual service :-)